# Can't send HTTP requests from my Windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, windows-8.1

I have a Xamarin.Forms app project in VS2015 which consumes a REST service inside my network.
Android and iOS versions of this project worked connecting and getting data from localhost and from the published service in my network, but with Windows 8 app only worked in localhost, when I try to get data from the service in my network I only get this in Output console:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in mscorlib.dll
                ERROR An error occurred while sending the request.
```

Is there a permission or security constraint that I'm missing?

I forgot to say that the web service is at port 5000 like this:
http://localhost:5000/api/clients or http://192.168.10.23:5000/api/clients
Not sure if is related or is there any policy to restrict which ports to listen in a Win8 app.

Edit 2:

```
I think I should include the method where the exception is thrown:

    public async Task<List<Client>> LoadClientsAsync(string query)
            {
                var Items = new List<Client>();

                // RestUrl = http://192.168.10.100:5000/api/clients{0}

                var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("?q=");
                sb.Append(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(query));

                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, sb.ToString() ));

                try
                {

                    var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(uri); 
//Here is where exception is thrown
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Client>>(content);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
                }

                return Items;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because was trying to send requests to a service in the local network, Enabling the "**Private Networks (Client & Server)**" Capability in the Package.appxmanifest make it work.